React Native Expo: Can not connect to metro
When I run npx expo start from my project, The app does not load and I get an error message "Can not connect to metro" on the android emulator and an "Disconnected from metro" error message on ios.
If I run expo client:install:android or expo client:install:android first and then run npx expo start, the error message does not appear and the app loads successfully. However, every time I close and restart my app, I have to run these commands again before npx expo start. What can I do to make sure I don't have to run them every time I start the app?
I have Expo Go installed on the emulators.
